# 0x80048470 - Importing CRM Solution

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am trying to import an unmanaged solution but for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
Failure: 0x80048470 - The entity relationship role of the referencing entity is required when creating a new one-to-many entity relationship business_unit_new_contract.
```

It's interesting because I've opened the costumizations.xml and the relationship is there. Also, when I look up at the exported solution entity that has the relationship, the relationship is also displayed.

At first, I was receiving an 0x8004803A error as shown:

```
Failure: 0x8004803A - The import has failed because component  of type 50 is not declared in the solution file as a root component. To fix this, import again using the XML file that was generated when you exported the solution.
```

So, I opened the solution.xml and added a new  for that particular type, which was not in the file.

Has anyone ever experienced that? Also, This relationship shown is between businessunit and one of my entities.

Is there any way of fixing it through database? What would be the best solution?

Thanks in advance,
Dem

Answer (score 1):

I'll just try to explain your second problem (0x8004803A), since it happened to me today.

By the way, this was one of the few times when 'Download log' was actually helpful (it contained the real error).

> The import has failed because component  of type 50 is not declared in the solution file as a root component.

Entity type code 50 apparently stands for (global) `Application Ribbon`. This can happen when manually adding the `<RibbonXmlDiff />` section to customizations.xml. If this happens it is enough to add following line to solution.xml:

```
<RootComponents>
  ...
  <RootComponent type="50" schemaName=":RibbonDiffXml" />
</RootComponents>
```